# How to avoid time overlapping in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-5

I am building a laravel application where In a controller I want to book a room with some time gap and if someone already booked that room with that time it will forbid the user to book that room in that time interval. How do I solve the problem?

I have written a Query in my controller for checking time range but it's not working properly.

> Eg: if a user want to book a room from 12:00 to 12:30, but someone
>   already has booked that room from 12:15 to 12:45, controller won't let
>   book that room.

Here is my controller:

```
 public function postAllocateRoom(Request $request)
    {

            $classRoom = new ClassRoom();  

            $classRoom->department_id=$request->Input(['department_id']);     
            $classRoom->room_id=$request->Input(['room_id']); 
            $classRoom->course_id=$request->Input(['course_id']); 
            $classRoom->day_id=$request->Input(['day_id']); 
            $classRoom->start=$request->Input(['start']); 
            $classRoom->end=$request->Input(['end']);  
            $startTime = Carbon::parse($request->input('start'));
            $endTime = Carbon::parse($request->input('end'));

          $room=DB::select('SELECT allocate_rooms.id 
                FROM allocate_rooms
WHERE "' . $startTime . '" BETWEEN allocate_rooms.start AND allocate_rooms.end AND
     "' . $endTime . '" BETWEEN allocate_rooms.start AND allocate_rooms.end');

            $messages ="Class Room Already Taken";
            if ($room) {
             return redirect('allocateRoomPage');
                    }
            else { 
                 $classRoom->save();            
            return redirect('allocateRoomPage');  
            }                   
    }
```

Comment: So what problem are you facing?

Comment: Query doesn't work actually, means I can book 12:00 o'clock  room though someone already booked it before in that time.

Comment: What about this: 'SELECT allocate_rooms.id 
                FROM allocate_rooms
WHERE "' . $startTime . '" BETWEEN allocate_rooms.start AND allocate_rooms.end AND
    ( "' . $endTime . '" BETWEEN allocate_rooms.start AND allocate_rooms.end)'

Comment: I wanted to check if it has any value, instead of saving in database it will redirected to same page again. It's just my own concept to solve the problem, there could be different solution!

Comment: Yups I know. What I am saying is put brackets "()" for the second where clause after AND.

Comment: Here is the new problem I'm facing : I have already booked the time 12:00 am to 12:30 am in database and when I'm booking the time with same value again it's saving like: 00:00 to 00:30.

Comment: Can you post more info. Like what are you getting in $request->input('start'), $request->input('end') etc? Just dd() the request values.

Comment: I'm giving input as 2:00:00 and after  dd() I'm getting:

`Carbon {#220 ▼
  +"date": "2016-05-09 02:00:00.000000"
  +"timezone_type": 3
  +"timezone": "UTC"
}`

Answer (score 1):

The following logic checks whether the booking time interval is clash with the current allocated room's time interval or not. It's just the logic, you may need to modify as proper.

```
if (($booking_start_time < $allocated_room_start_time && $booking_end_time < $allocated_room_start_time) || ($booking_start_time > $allocated_room_end_time && $booking_end_time > $allocated_room_end_time)) {
    // No time clash
}else{
   // Time clashed !!
}
```

Hope this help.